# TestFlight External Testing Review Status Not Changed

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I have uploaded a iOS test build to TestFlight for external testing. Submitted the beta build for review and the build status has moved to **"In Review" and again moved to "Testing"**. Today is 10th day of submission and still the status is in "Testing".  I referred about Beta approval in documents, those says it will take maximum 1-2 days. But, for me almost 10 days passed. Build is not available to share with Testers.
Can anyone please tell me the Beta Review status changes? What should I do now? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: apple once in apple review team or else upload the new build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Status "Testing" means it has completed review and is available to your testers.

The statuses are:

- Ready to Submit
- In Review
- Testing

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you please list the Review Statuses? Thanks.